# JS - modular programming

Tags: javascript

I want to write a program, that displays a rect, when the mouse clicks on the canvas element. I have certain modules, but somehow they seem not to be connected. I pasted the the code without a namespace in a JSFidlle:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGKDA/)

**displaying module**

```
(function(){
    display = (function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        return {            
            canvas: canvas,     
            context : context 
        }
    })();
})();
```

**manager-module**

```
(function(){
    manager = (function(){
        var canvas = display.canvas;    
        var context = display.context ;
        var rect = function(){
            ctx.fillRect(10,10,20,20);
        }
        return {
            rect: rect
        }
    })();
})();
```

**main-module**

```
(function(){
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        manager.rect;
    }, 0);  
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to *call* the manager.rect function. Add some `()` in main-module and you'll be fine.

Essentially what you're doing in **manager-module** is this:

```
manager.rect = function () { ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20); };
```

Now when you access `manager.rect`, it'll return the *value* `function () { ... }`, because that's the content of the `.rect` property.
You need to add parentheses `()`, to tell the JS engine that it should call the function, not just retrieve it.

Comment: @Reanimation thank you for the fast answer, it works, but why do I need the (), I thought the function is in variable rect as a function?

Comment: Because JavaScript uses `()` to call functions and property accesses are not function calls. I've edited in some small explanation.

Answer (score 0):

They are all in their own anonymous function, so they are all in their own namespace. If you'd like each section to be able to communicate with each other put all the code in only one anonymous function.

Comment: They don't use the `var` keyword and will default to the global namespace. Ugly and unmaintainable, but it works.

Comment: New to me, you learn something everyday, will remove this answer soon then.